# How to use html UTI symbol shortcuts like &trade; with angularjs ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, symbols, uti

I'm repeating the following element:

```
<li ng-repeat="feature in pTab.features">
    <p>{{feature.summary}}</p>
</li>
```

feature.summary is a string from a .txt file and contains `&trade;` where trademark symbols should be displayed.However the page simply displays `&trade;` as text on the page.

Looking at the [W3 Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_letterlike.asp), I thought this should display as a tradmark symbol on the page.

Does this not work with AngularJS or do I need to correct something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

> Evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element in a secure way.

*Code*

```
<p ng-bind-html="feature.summary"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. However, the summary stopped displaying when I did this. Any idea why? I can post more of the HTML if necessary.

Comment: I ran into this issue, as well. This was the error in the console: "angular.min.js:107 Error: [$sce:unsafe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$sce/unsafe
    at Error (native)"